# PhoneGap 2.1 and Facebook SDK 3.1 on iOS - com.facebook.sdk Error 2 on device

Tags: cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins

I have just updated my PhoneGap iOS app to the latest version 2.1.
Since it uses Facebook login I also updated the Facebook Connect Plugin as showed [here](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/tree/pg2.1-ios3.1).

The Facebook login runs smoothly on the emulator (using both iOS 5.1 and 6.0) but I got an error on the device (using iOS 6) 
"The operation couldn't be completed com.facebook.sdk Error 2"

It seems to be a problem with the BundleID of my app not matching the one on the Facebook app.
I checked that **BundleIdentifier** and **BundleURLName** in my info.plist file match the Bundle ID under Native iOS app in the settings of my Facebook app.

If someone could help me understand what's wrong...
Thanks a lot.

Comment: So far, the only way to fix it was downgrading to Phonegap 2.0 and Facebook SDK 3.0

Comment: I am also having same problem. Did you find a way to handle it except downgrading?

Comment: Having the same problem too. :(

Comment: Check out this pull request on the git repository, it has some information: https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/pull/216

Answer (score 5):

This error could also happen if the app has been turned off on the Facebook iOS6 settings. Go to the device Settings app, check Facebook and see if your app is turned off, by checking the "Allow These Apps to Use Your Account:" section.

For a related discussion, if you find this to be the issue, see [SDK 3.1: How to tell whether SDK is using iOS6 accounts or not?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12712204/sdk-3-1-how-to-tell-whether-sdk-is-using-ios6-accounts-or-not)

Comment: I turned on my app in settings>facebook.But showing the same error " error in operation(com.facebook.sdk error 2)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. This answer helped me:
[Facebook ios sdk 3.0 active session FBiOSSDK error2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591637/facebook-ios-sdk-3-0-active-session-fbiossdk-error2/13964450#13964450)

Briefly, I was trying to login to a sandbox mode FB app with a tester account. Try an admin account and/or make sandbox off.

Comment: +1 for making sure the Facebook user you are trying to post through is registered with the app, or making sure that sandbox mode is off.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Deleted facebook account in IOS Settings
2. logged out of facebook app and deleted from iPhone
3. Logged out of facebook messenger and deleted app from iPhone
4. Redeployed my app to my iPhone

Problem solved finally after days of googling for com.facebook.sdk error

My bundle id in the build settings and plist don't match by the way.....

On reinstalling the facebook app, and then trying to login to FB from my app I got a message telling me to set my bundle id in developer.facebook.com/app so it may have been that problem before, but i'm not sure since i could login to fb from my app after taking the steps above.